# How can I get a pair of text selectors that have been indexed and determined by the previous scheme?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form designed like this.
[form display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exox4.jpg)

the text inputs was generate by dynamics data list like 5x5, 6x6, 7x7 .... N x N.

How can i get a pairs of inputs text selector like this [display format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHprg.png) ?

But I just knew the selector index like this [cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4JPe.png)

I've been tried to get data pair from each selector like an images before, but i just get pairs of  1 with 6 indexed selector in data 6x6 format.

```
$('input').each(function (index) {         
         var $index = index;
         $(this).focus(function(e){
            var $iPos = ($index * ordo) + $index;
            var $iPosTarget = $iPos - $index;
            console.log('indexText : ' + $index + ', indexDivision: ' + $iPos + ' , indexTarget: ' + $iPosTarget);

});
```

I had `HTML` like :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="1"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="2"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="5.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="3"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="8.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="4"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="5"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="2.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="7"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="8"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="7.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="9"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="9.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="10"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="5.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="11"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="4.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="12"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.20" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="13"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.14" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="14"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="15"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="16"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="17"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="2.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="18"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.13" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="19"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.11" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="20"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="21"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="22"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.25" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="23"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="24"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="25"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.20" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="26"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="27"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="4.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="28"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="29"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.50" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="31"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.25" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="32"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.50" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="33"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="34"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="35"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="36"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="3.16" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="2.7" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="14.16" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="28" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="13.25" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="10.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I expect to get pair of inputs like 
(1) with (6), (2) with (12), (8) with (13), (3) with (18) ..... up to (29) with (34)

Comment: not clear, some further explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: also it would help us if you add the `HTML` part.

Comment: @ths sorry about my bad english explaination, :'

Comment: no problem, you did your best. Just make sure to update the question with the related `HTML` part so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ths it was dynamically generated by how much scheme like 6x6, 7x7, ... n x n

Comment: So let's assume we have a 3*3 puzzle, how should it be displayed ? Are the numbers in the puzzle random or choosed manually ? The intended result after fetching the pairs ?

Comment: For a cell with value `x`, it is in row `x // n` (floor divide) and column `x % n` (modulo), so all you need to do is swap them to get the matching cell with value `y = n * (x % n) + (x // n)`.

Comment: @ths number is random, but i just need the pair "index" of `<input>` inside table with scheme like the `1st` index of inputs will pairs with `6th` index of inputs. its like comparison matrix of Analytic Hierarchy Process tables. :o

Comment: @StardustGogeta can u explain with math example ??

Comment: @PungkyPriyo Try putting in `x=29` and `n=6`, and you will get `y=34`. See what I mean?

Comment: @StardustGogeta I was update my explained case images. please check :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but this is my best guess. All I did was swap the row index with the column index to get the other associated input.

```js
$('tr').each(function (rowIndex) {
  $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function (colIndex) {
    $(this).focus(function(e){
      if(rowIndex != colIndex){
        $('input[type=text]').removeClass('highlighted')
        var other = $('tr:eq('+colIndex+') input[type=text]:eq('+rowIndex+')')
        other.addClass('highlighted')
        $(this).addClass('highlighted')
        console.log($(this).val()+'<->'+other.val())
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="1"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="2"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="5.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="3"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="8.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="4"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="5"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="2.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="7"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="8"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="7.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="9"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="9.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="10"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="5.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="11"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="4.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="12"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.20" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="13"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.14" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="14"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="15"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="16"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="17"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="2.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="18"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.13" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="19"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.11" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="20"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="21"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="22"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.25" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="23"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="24"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="25"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.20" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="26"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="27"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="4.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="28"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="29"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.50" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="31"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.25" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="32"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="0.50" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="33"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="3.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="34"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="35"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inText" name="bobot_k1[]" value="1.00" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="inTextBobotIdK-1" name="bobot_id_k1[]" value="36"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="3.16" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="2.7" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="14.16" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="28" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="13.25" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
<td><input class="form-control-sm form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inTextTotalK-1" disabled="disabled" value="10.33" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```